# json schemas: Is type necessary when const or enum are present?

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

When a property has `const` or `enum`, what are the benefits or downsides of proving `type` too?

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "has_car": {
      "title": "Do you have a car?",
      "enum": ["yes", "no"],
      "type": "string",
      "$comment": "Do I need type here?"
    },
    "car_brand": {
      "title": "What's your car brand?",
      "type": "string"
    },
    "terms": {
      "title": "I accept my car terms",
      "const": "acknowledged",
      "$comment": "Do I need type here?"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There really is no benefit. `const` and `enum` verify exact values, so `type` adds nothing, as you suspect.

Comment: Just to clarify one last thing: The official docs say:
 "A JSON value interpreted according to this data model is called an "instance". [...] An instance has one of six primitive types, and a range of possible values depending on the type". 
So, by reading this it implicitly states the type is required. But you are saying it adds nothing. So... could you clarify that? Thank you @gregsdennis!

Comment: `const` and `enum` are applicable to ALL types in the instance data, while `properties` for example is only applicable to objects.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not required because keywords are applied separately. Depending upon what is using the schema it can help to define both. For code generation, adding type helps because one can limit the allowed input types with that info. So that is a potential benefit.

One downside is that your schema definition is larger, and that if new enum values are added with different types are added, those new types need to be added also.